# remove variables through an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to delete values of a lot of variables inside an array:

```
var fbUserID = String()
var fbUserName = String()
var meNickname = String()
var userIDOneSignal = String()

var deleteStrings = [fbUserID, fbUserName, meNickname, userIDOneSignal]
```

Is it possible to do something in line of this:

```
for i in deleteStrings {
    i.removeAll()//remove all as in remove the values of each variable
}
```

I've also tried using `deleteStrings[i].removeAll()`

Comment: You should use a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to value semantics you cannot mutate variables (as a pointer) from an array.

Rather than an array use a struct

```
struct User {

    var fbUserID = "12"
    var fbUserName = "Foo"
    var meNickname = "Baz"
    var userIDOneSignal = "123"

    mutating func clear()
    {
        fbUserID = ""
        fbUserName = ""
        meNickname = ""
        userIDOneSignal = ""
    }
}

var user = User()
print(user.fbUserID) // "12"
user.clear()

user.fbUserID = ""
print(user.fbUserID) // ""
```

Comment: Why not simply declare all properties with let and instead of "clear" just instantiate a new struct

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, that's better but I wanted to keep the basic "workflow" of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the array elements

```
deleteStrings.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `class` inherits from `NSObject`, you can use [*key value coding*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyvaluecoding) to access the fields by name:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var fbUserID = String()
    var fbUserName = String()
    var meNickname = String()
    var userIDOneSignal = String()

    var deleteStrings = ["fbUserID", "fbUserName", "meNickname", "userIDOneSignal"]

    func clearAll() {
        deleteStrings.forEach { setValue("", forKey: $0) }
    }
}

let user = User()
user.fbUserID = "12345"
user.fbUserName = "Joseph Doe"
user.meNickname = "Joe"

print(user.meNickname)  // "Joe"

user.clearAll()

print(user.meNickname)  // ""
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete/remove variable value then use optional otherwise your variable value only gets removed or become non-existence when it goes out of scope.

For Example:

```
var a: Int? = 5  // it have default value 5
a = nil // Now a have nil which is kind of telling that it contains nothing which is what you want to achieve
```

Now coming to your question.

> Is it possible to do something in line of this:

```
for i in deleteStrings {
    i.removeAll()   
}
```

You are iterating over an array of strings and then for each string, you are trying to remove all the `characters`. First of all you will get error

```
 error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'i' is a 'let' constant
```

Even though you will correct is using `var` it will not achieve what you are trying to do i.e. `I want to delete the variables value` because still your `fbUserID ...` all other variables will have copies of the data you initialised with.

Now how to do it?

- You can use optional to achieve it.

  ```
  var fbUserID: String? = String()
  var fbUserName: String? = String()
  var meNickname: String? = String()
  var userIDOneSignal: String? = String()

  // To delete you will need to assign them nil
  fbUserId = nil
  ```

Again, you can't do them over loop because `var` are of values type and when you add it to the list their copies get added.

Comment: The OP wants non-optional empty strings. Optionals are a bad suggestion in this case.

Comment: @vadian I thought, he asked ways to empty the string. Optional is one way to represent it. BTW thanks for the reply.

Comment: An empty string and an optional `nil` string are two completely different things. Face the huge benefit of non-optional values: The code will never crash at **runtime** and the compiler prevents assigning an optional value at **compile time**.

Comment: I agree. My concern was 'Delete Variable' != 'Empty String'. I thought 'Delete Variable' in terms of 'NULL/NIL'.